# How ca i do a query in to a Map with dynamic id?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with a Collection of products, these products belong a Store,  so i  denormalized my collections  "Products" and "Store" like this:
[image: Simple collection of Store]

In Products i have a map with the ID of store, i do that to do Multi-path Updates.[image: Store Collection]

Finally i need to do a Search by name of Store or name of product into Product's collection, I tried whith a Index in firestore, but the ID's map is Dynamic so i can't config.

With this Structure i can control Data consistency with Multi-path updates if any Store changes their data, but it's a problem for me to do a Query using where.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The query you're trying to do is not possible with the data you have now.  If you're trying to search products by name of the store, the store name must be in field that has a consistent name.  If there can be multiple stores for a single product, you can instead use a list field and put all the names of the stores in that list.  For example, if the name of the list field was "stores", you can use an [array-contains query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

```
firestore.collection("products").where("stores", "array-contains", storeName)
```

Comment: Thank you @Doug Stevenson for your answer,  I'm trying  that because I need pay attention in Data consistency with Multi-path updates and atomic operation, if the store's name change, i need to update store's name in all products, Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you know what you need to do.  What you're describing is common for nosql type databases where data duplication is required.  Use a transcation or batch write for atomic updates.